# Add Listview and its adapter in RemoteView

Tags: android, listview, remoteview

I am trying to add a layout containing textview, Imageview, listview in itself. I am accessing this layout using RemoteViews and displaying in frame layout. 
Textview, Imageview are displaying but not listview and its item.

Can anyone guide me on this context?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. I am not asking to add list view in widget app.

Comment: Have you used Scrollview as parent view? if Yes, then the **listview** has the issue with scroll view. I that I can suggest you work with **recycler view** inside the scroll view

Comment: No. I did not use. Recycler view can not be used in RemoteViews.

Comment: I guess, No one implemented this earlier.

Comment: I am successfully able to implement Imageview and Textview. but still facing problem in Listview. 
I am eagerly waiting for reply.